# C# - Delayed execution for a collection of items

Tags: c#, while-loop, thread-sleep

I have a collection of 100,000 items. Item has 2 properties. (1) Time Stamp and (2) Data. Each item in the collection is having a time stamp which is either equal to more than the previous items by a few (varying) milliseconds. I need to send these items to a TCP endpoint maintaining the time delay between them. ie, if the time difference between 1st and 2nd item is 300ms, then after sending first item, I should wait 300ms and then send the second item.

After finding the time difference between consecutive items, I tried Thread.Sleep. For the list which has a time difference of 40 seconds between the very first item and very last item, with Thread.Sleep it was taking around 70-80 seconds to send all the items.

```
DateTime currenTimeStamp;
DateTime nextTimeStamp;
TimeSpan timeDiff;

using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        //some lines here to do the TCP transfer

        currenTimeStamp = //get current item's time stamp;
        nextTimeStamp = //get next item's time stamp;
        timeDiff = nextTimeStamp - currenTimeStamp;
        Thread.Sleep(timeDiff);
    }
}
```

Later I tried waiting in a while loop by comparing the current time and the expected time to send. That was taking around 50-55 seconds to process the entire items. Also the CPU is busy the entire time with the while loop.

```
DateTime currenTimeStamp;
DateTime nextTimeStamp;
DateTime TimeToSendNextItem;
TimeSpan timeDiff;

using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        //some lines here to do the TCP transfer

        currenTimeStamp = //get current item's time stamp;
        nextTimeStamp = //get next item's time stamp;
        timeDiff = nextTimeStamp - currenTimeStamp;
        TimeToSendNextItem = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(timeDiff);
        while (DateTime.UtcNow < TimeToSendNextItem) { }
    }
}
```

How can I handle this with minimum lag, and efficiently? By minimum lag, I mean to  send these items within a time as close to the original 40 seconds time difference between first and last item.

Comment: Have you tried to use `async`?

Comment: As noted, you should make your function `async` and then use `Task.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep`. But, getting that kind of timing right will be very difficult. You will likely need to reduce your delay to compensate for the task switching and communications overhead. Read this week's StackOverflow blog (on music programming) to understand an approach to dealing g with this kind of problem

Comment: Try this 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I'll assume `//some lines here to do the TCP transfer` is taking time. You need to taking operation time into account. Your sleep time shall be the timeDiff - operation cost.

Comment: Re-read your question and I found it's a tough case. Operation 100000 times and they takes 10~15 seconds total, which means each operation is taking 0.1 ms more than you expect. If 0.1 ms is unacceptable, post commented code snipped `//some lines here to do the TCP transfer` might help.

Comment: @LouisGo Actually the TCP communication is to a process within the same system and was not causing much delay. Even after commenting that TCP call, the total time it took was more or less the same. Also, the 100000 records was a sample data. The actuals could be data for 2 hours. With increase in count of items, the delay when using Sleep/Delay/While was increasing exponentially. As commented by you and Flydog57 I shall include logic to compnesate for switching and communication overhead.

Comment: @Flydog57 Thanks for your comment, I shall go through the StackOverflow blog post on music programming.

Comment: You should measure the elapsed time since the very beginning and only `Thread.Sleep` / `await Task.Delay` if this item is *early*. However the TCP stream may be the limiting factor in how long it takes to transfer all the data, making the delivery of other items *late*.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the latest C# 8.0 you could use an `IAsyncEnumerable` to give you the items as you need them:

```
private async IAsyncEnumerable<Item> GetItemAfterDelay(IEnumerable<Item> items)
{
    DateTime previousItemTimestamp = items.First().Timestamp;

    foreach(var i in items)
    {
        var delay = i.Timestamp - previousItemTimestamp;

        await Task.Delay(delay);

        yield return i;

        previousItemTimestamp = i.Timestamp;
    }
}
```

NOTE: I have created a class called `Item` to represent your collection item.

```
struct Item
{
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

This method will return one item from the array after the difference between the current timestamp and the previous one.

You can then use iterate over the items returned and do the TCP transfer.

```
using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
{
    // assuming your collection is called `myCollection`
    await foreach(var item in GetItemAfterDelay(myCollection))
    {
        //some lines here to do the TCP transfer
    }
}
```

Comment: The delay is still wrong. Your delay will grow to be the sum of all the delays. It should be based on the elapsed wall-clock time from when you yielded the first item.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Good spot. I forgot to change the current timestamp value.

Comment: You're still assuming that no time will elapse between yielded values.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to measure the elapsed time from the first item you send, then ensure that no item is processed early. Since other factors outside your control could cause processing delays. (assuming c#8);

```cs
private async IAsyncEnumerable<Item> GetItemAfterDelay(IEnumerable<Item> items)
{
    var e = items.GetEnumerator();
    if (e.MoveNext()){
       var started = DateTime.Now;
       var firstTime = e.Current.Timestamp;
       yield return e.Current;
       while(e.MoveNext()){
          var delay = (e.Current.Timestamp - firstTime) - (DateTime.Now - started);
          if (delay >0)
             await Task.Delay(delay);
          yield return e.Current;
       }
    }
}

await foreach(var item in GetItemAfterDelay(items)){
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to take `//some lines here to do the TCP transfer` operation time into account. ( If they're synchronous. )

I'll using your first code snippet for example.

```
DateTime currenTimeStamp;
DateTime nextTimeStamp;
TimeSpan timeDiff;

using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var start = DateTime.Now;
        //some lines here to do the TCP transfer
        var operationDiff = DateTime.Now - start;
        currenTimeStamp = //get current item's time stamp;
        nextTimeStamp = //get next item's time stamp;
        timeDiff = nextTimeStamp - currenTimeStamp - operationDiff;
        Thread.Sleep(timeDiff);
    }
}
```

Edit: 
Since you have 100,000 items, actual operation time is 10~15 more than expected.
That's 0.1 ms per item, edit your post for `//some lines here to do the TCP transfer` if you need more help.

Also `Thread.Sleep` precision depends on hardware clock. If you need more precision timing, you may need real-time library and specific hardware (for clock).

Using while is asking process to "don't stop, keep checking", so it will take less time to operate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code using Timers.

```
        class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Adding elements to list");
            List<WorkItem> workItems = new List<WorkItem>(100);
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                workItems.Add(new WorkItem
                {
                    TimeStamp = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(i * 300)
                });
            }
            var tw = new TimedWorker();
            tw.Process(workItems);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    class TimedWorker
    {
        private Timer _timer;
        private Queue<WorkItem> _workItems;
        public void Process(List<WorkItem> workItems)
        {
            _timer = new Timer
            {
                AutoReset = false,
                Interval = 1
            };
            _workItems = new Queue<WorkItem>();
            _timer.Elapsed += Elapsed;
            foreach (var item in workItems)
            {
                _workItems.Enqueue(item);
            }
            _timer.Start();
        }

        private void Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            ProcessNext();
        }

        private void ProcessNext()
        {
            var item = _workItems.Dequeue();
            var nextItem = _workItems.Peek();
            _timer.Interval = (nextItem.TimeStamp - item.TimeStamp).TotalMilliseconds;
            Console.WriteLine(item.TimeStamp.ToString("hh/mm/ss:FFFFFF"));
            _timer.Start();
        }
    }

    class WorkItem
    {
        public DateTime TimeStamp;
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure if we can consider delays in TCP operation which is going to be very random, based on multiple factors.
IMO we can only manage to call actual function (NW operation in this case) within given time frame. BUt as per @Louis we can include average operation delay.

Answer (score -1):

Remember, when you use the Thread class, the operating system has control over the process that is executing, you can not control the execution time, having said that, I Dont think you can solve the problem using Thread class.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer